# Editing Date and Time in python through SQLite3

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, user-interface, tkinter, datetimeformatinfo

I am making a library system in tkinter and using SQLite3 as my DB. I have to take date as input from system which I can take by using "from datetime import date" but in one cell I wanna add 7 days to that particular date.
Eg. if one column is showing today's date 24-03-2019 then another column should show (date+ 7 days) i.e. 31-03-2019.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use directly sqlite

```
bc@hal9000:~$ sqlite3
SQLite version 3.16.2 2017-01-06 16:32:41
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
Connected to a transient in-memory database.
Use ".open FILENAME" to reopen on a persistent database.
sqlite> SELECT date('now', '+7 days');
2019-03-31
```